# Echarts with multi-lines and custom cross axisPointer

Tags: javascript, echarts

I would like to do this in echarts:
[image]
with axisPointer in mode cross without the label in-between graph, the label show only in the last graph at bottom, is it possible ?

Actually my code show this:
https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-line-chart-forked-2dc4mq?file=/index.html
[image]

This is the sandbox code from ECharts live here:
[Echarts with multi-lines](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=line-simple&code=G4QwTgBA9gDgLgSygOwgXggbwFATxOKKAG0RgC4td8a4wEBzBgUzEoHIQAPBAZ3YA01Gnm58AClATI4rSpjgBPGMw4BjMFF78AvsIg6hNMb0nTZbKiIjFpAa0oBtfTRzWaXAII9eASWQAJsxcHCDExIIu-IZRALpGIrbIzADKSsSqVu4A7ggBcAAWlACMCdZqJFCW7AxgIIqR7gTKmewBILwFzAGNIjHWxCAARszE8lF4nVDZlHQArsxl0Uv9-LV5TlFu7hUyINIAMsOjs2ALSzRTMwRnixMEsCUADE8X-F2MBXCUAEwvb6tXPddnB9sgjiMxjdzvcrqcYU1CBQID8AJyve4fBhfX4vKKA_DbcooUGHY5Q-Z3Jpw6FU9xIygAFgAHBimlicSi8dY9DR4vovD5NtYiSIlCp1CBZAwqg03pMCtNKAAzMK8OnWdYBfxBEIQNnuIZQOaBcCKADiIGRquI6oBb1FtBakulst61hpNrt9y1OuCJXlECNJvaYAtVpVao1yy293FrTUUuYMrD7pEvsC_pRgeDprDlutUYB-n5NEU3j4wpEjvw8Y4oGICzTNAzusoBpoBLwNbwdYg7AbTcDrazpXxDrjzv7g-YzbW9G1mb1P3tJaW6vozF4VZF9xoyBAAFtWgBRQ_7YjFOfWPvsJKzwM0dqgpzFP4CCDFADMK8_T1Kn5foyH7oh-Pxfq8KLFE8pZNPggp8H6eodnB5Y-Eh7aBl2hJ7vgB7HhwZ4Xj815ilOd7SA-uF4M-ICvv8EAAKyQcUzEfqyIEsQxzGwXBEAIX4S4BtREBoYhQmflhgY9iI-GnueCDEF-pFOhK_b3ip-C0U4X5fmBDGMpBEGcR-0EfjBj7wRWglttmIliTZWYrvcvL4LE2A6AA3EAA)

anyone may help me ?

thanks

Comment: You can disable the tooltip with `showContent: false`

Comment: no I want disabled the axisPointer label (where you see [2] in the snapshot) for graph 1 and 2 and keep label only for last graph, ShowContent control only the tooltip content. thanks for trying to help.

Comment: Do you need to use multiple grids? If you would use multiple axes instead there would not be this issue.

Comment: see this [example](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=line-simple&code=G4QwTgBA9gDgLgSygOwgXggbwFAQnKKAG0RgC4tc98wEBzOgUzAoHIQAPBAZ1YBoqeTjwAKUBMjjMKmfAE8YjNgGMwUbrwgBfKloF4OAQS7cKAbUGVq1OAqURWykFLpQwc_pbzcAFlADuFABmIETcjPrWEABGUACuyAAm4HIA4iDkECFhjJY6eAC6kXLGPOaWOFHyimygRHGMrHmReJVRtjUOdQ1N1noVXtX2rN2NLdQw6giIKGy0dD5wnlVQQUHhcBQAzAAMeVRFVOG0jKYQFtZt1h3DRBJjgyUmAJJJjBwUO-N4yXAg5gBGABMXwgAK2QL4YJ2AKh4IALFCAJygoG7KFAgE7ArNAZVG5sO7IB5VJ48V6Jd4UWGDX7_c5Y0EAVlBAJZUIAHKCUXCdszsbjLoMCQ4iSSomTuBSqRBIbTnPSzFsthi-VD4aD0RAedCoQK-gdsFoANxAA)

Comment: Thanks Matthias for your answer, but my client want graphs on severals grid. I want control the axisPointer label, I tried to modify the formatter to detect the axisIndex and return null, but the label still empty with a backgroundColor box visible.

Comment: You can remove all labels with `tooltip: { axisPointer: { type: 'cross', label: { show: false } } }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I think I got something now. You can set the [`backgroundColor`](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#axisPointer.label.backgroundColor) of `axisPointer.label` to `'transparent'` in order to disable the box drawn by echarts (note that for some reason it also makes the text color transparent which has to be set manually). Then you can use the [formatter function](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#axisPointer.label.formatter) together with [rich text labeling](https://echarts.apache.org/en/tutorial.html#Rich%20Text) to add a box and labels yourself, depending on the `axisIndex`.

[Here](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=line-simple&code=G4QwTgBA9gDgLgSygOwgXggbwFATxOKKAG0RgC4td8a4wEBzBgUzEoHIQAPBAZ3YA01Gnm58AClATI4rSpjgBPGMw4BjMFF78AvsIg6hNMb0nTZbKiIjFpAa0oBtfTRzWaXAII9eASWQAJsxcHCDExIIu-IZRALpGIsQgAEbMxPJReLwAFlAA7pR0AK7MCdYAZlBgALYgcBaFzLxwZSLJIGp2DJpFgQDCJFUcdCDIvDDgzDKR7hBqg5bsyUmdM-70atkZs3jJUCFWO7sdXT39CxzdzIprRxMBAdIMlACsmdHvetYxND_43QgAk4om53PMZCBpAAZFJpQpgEqtGg5fLwxHvQgUCAARgADLikfhssxGNk4JQAEz4wl_VzvcFwSHIGGpdIEBGld4ogrs9GzTGUgCcBPexNJ5IgVNxUVp-FB1gZTJZcN5nNm3LRavcAogABYABwi2Zihhkyn4mX6eL6Lw-YHWeUiJQqdR1ZgMKo3QlZXI88phXha6wAgL-IIHI3uPa9ALgRQAcRAWP9xEDNMJjtoylUEHYajdHrAXq5vsoKbT7xDYeClGx3og0cCccTyYDQeiGYx2ddskLxdmVcCNcl9cbsaLLbLbZpVtaim8fHtIkz-GdOfYoGIJVuIkH4cokd-nf53dzm-39b3w7rMuP2tPG7CF8r9FDQ4OFPTs_0gfoTSXDrvDQyAgNU64AKK1AgxDYjuJ4urmtjIMwcHuLGjJONiVICDiADMn44ridZ4bqOHCjhFK4QSkp4taRx4LafDVhG9Y0POPjMQe9aynS9EQCBYEcJBkLEBSqHWGuHBIShrH4OhICYdSEAvNR2IqThhpkapSkqXR9GMX4761rJeDsUxRk4tx9YrtYAkQVBxC4eJToPtJzk0PJTi4bhFFKbq1FUVpOF4jhuJ6UcBmcSOQH4GZhn7tFsxfPgsTYDoADc2DYOUvRqIgKAEE0cAABQTGAoG8AAlIcCDlBApXgBVAB0JgACIIGBYxIKgaC9bmNwQAAPoNEBlc1JjMegfUUtVjpgMwcBFGAqAAESYHsXCDStEAANQQAAsnU2RNWcAQNeV1S8E157MNVe0rToK2ZXgeg6EAA) is a small example:

```js
option = {
  tooltip: {
    trigger: 'axis',
    axisPointer: { type: 'cross' }
  },
  axisPointer: {
    link: [
      {
        xAxisIndex: 'all'
      }
    ],
    label: {
      show: true,
      formatter: test,
      backgroundColor: 'transparent',
      color: 'black',
      rich: {
        box: {
          backgroundColor: 'grey',
          padding: 5
        }
      }
    }
  },
  grid: [
    {
      containLabel: true,
      show: true,
      top: 100,
      height: 200
    },
    {
      containLabel: true,
      show: true,
      top: 290,
      height: 200
    },
    {
      containLabel: true,
      show: true,
      top: 480,
      height: 200
    }
  ],
  xAxis: [
    {
      type: 'category',
      show: false,
      gridIndex: 0,
      boundaryGap: false
    },
    {
      type: 'category',
      show: false,
      gridIndex: 1,
      boundaryGap: false
    },
    {
      type: 'category',
      gridIndex: 2,
      boundaryGap: false
    }
  ],
  yAxis: [
    {
      type: 'value',
      gridIndex: 0
    },
    {
      type: 'value',
      gridIndex: 1
    },
    {
      type: 'value',
      gridIndex: 2
    }
  ],
  series: [
    {
      name: 'Email1',
      type: 'line',
      data: [120, 132, 101, 134, 90, 230, 210],
      xAxisIndex: 0,
      yAxisIndex: 0
    },
    {
      name: 'Email2',
      type: 'line',
      data: [100, 50, 150, 80, 90, 100, 50],
      xAxisIndex: 1,
      yAxisIndex: 1
    },
    {
      name: 'Email3',
      type: 'line',
      data: [33, 200, 40, 30, 90, 10, 0],
      xAxisIndex: 2,
      yAxisIndex: 2
    }
  ]
};

function test(params) {
  if (params.axisDimension === 'y' || params.axisIndex === 2) {
    return '{box|' + Math.round(params.value) + '}';
  }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate very much Matthias, thanks for your help !